# az commands to migrate secrets from 01 keyvault to 02 keyvault in azure

Tags: scripting, command, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, migrate

I need a script or az command to move my secrets from keyvault01 to keyvault02.

Does someone have az commands for that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have another Key Vault, or just want to move one to a new resource group or subscription. You can do that in the portal:

[image]

If you just need to move a few secrets you can do something like this using the cross-platform [Azure module for PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps):

```bsh
Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName MyOldVaultName -Name test* `
  | foreach { Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName MyOldVaultName -Name $_.Name } `
  | foreach { `
    Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName MyNewVaultName `
      -Name $_.Name `
      -SecretValue $_.SecretValue `
      -Expires $_.Expires `
      -Disable:(!$_.Enabled) `
      -ContentType $_.ContentType `
      -Tag $_.Tags }
```

You need to call `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret` twice because listing secrets does not download the secret value, so a second call with the specific secret value you want is necessary to retrieve it.